# bot.beginDialog to specific User and Channel

Tags: node.js, botframework

I'd like my bot to initiate a new conversation with other user at some point in the future. Rather than initiated by incoming POST message as in [Bot Connector Node.js](http://docs.botframework.com/connector/libraries/node/#navtitle) documentation, I'm trying to initiate from the conversation itself.

It's not so clear which one is the recommended approach for Node: 
Using  `require('botconnector')`,`ConnectorClient()`, or Bot Connector REST API.

However, based on [run-async](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/147fdc8f380dfd039b1c205ce7730a3a44c464bd/Node/examples/testBot/dialogs/run-async.js) and [LUIS](http://docs.botframework.com/builder/node/guides/understanding-natural-language/) example, I noticed `beginDialog` actually allows you to specify intended address: `bot.beginDialog(address, '/run-async/runner', { name: name });` or `cortanaBot.beginDialog({ from: alarm.from, to: alarm.to }, '/notify', alarm);`

I thought it's quite straightforward and clearer approach, however, the bot simply stops responding when I include such parameter (It works, if I just use `session.beginDialog('/myalarm', { alarm: "some alarm" });`). Do I miss out anything?

```
require('dotenv').config();
var restify = require('restify');
var builder = require('botbuilder');

// Get secrets from server environment
var botConnectorOptions = {
    appId: process.env.BOTFRAMEWORK_APPID,
    appSecret: process.env.BOTFRAMEWORK_APPSECRET
};

// Create bot
var bot = new builder.BotConnectorBot(botConnectorOptions);


function addressConverter(message) {
    return {
        to: message.from,
        from: message.to//,
        // conversationId: message.conversationId,
        // channelConversationId: message.channelConversationId,
        // channelMessageId: message.channelMessageId
    };
}


bot.add('/myalarm', function(session) {
    session.send('My Automatic Message');
    session.endDialog();
});


bot.add('/', function(session) {
    session.send('Hi');
    // Delay sending the reply for 5 seconds
    setTimeout(function() {
        session.send({ text: '5s Time out!' })
        var address = addressConverter(session.message);
        console.log("Message Address:")
        console.log(address)
        session.beginDialog(address, '/myalarm', { alarm: "some alarm" });
    }, 5000);
    session.send({ text: 'I will automatically message you in 5 seconds.' })
});

// Setup Restify Server
var server = restify.createServer();
//server.pre(restify.pre.pause());

// Handle Bot Framework messages
server.post('/api/messages', bot.verifyBotFramework(), bot.listen());

// Serve a static web page
server.get(/.*/, restify.serveStatic({
    'directory': '.',
    'default': 'index.html'
}));

server.listen(process.env.port || 3978, function() {
    console.log('%s listening to %s', server.name, server.url);
})
```

;